# NetLogo Code issues (trying to ignite fire using hex cell aggregation)

Tags: netlogo

We have a forest and randomized initial point of the fire set up, but the code fails to "ignite" (a function). Our goal is to have a hex cell aggregated model that can spread fire. Overall we want a forest fire that is more realistic by using hex cell aggregation.
Im positive that there is an issue with the eligibility or ignite function. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

**CODE:**

```
globals [
  initial-trees   ;; how many trees (green patches) we started with
  burned-trees    ;; how many have burned so far
  switches        ;; a list containing the number of switches that are on                                      ;;[So this is the start of the weird hex cell aggregation approach, if you don't wanna use
  eligibles       ;; a list of cells which are eligible to be ignited                                          ;; it that's all good, you just gotta delete like every instance of the words eligible,
]                                                                                                              ;; switches, and all of the read-switches stuff below and on the interface and get it to run]
;; The "switches" list is used so a cell can quickly check its live
;; neighbors count against the six switches without having to actually
;; inspect the switches one by one.  If the user flips a switch,
;; the list will be out of date, which is why we ask the user to
;; press the SETUP or READ-SWITCHES buttons after changing switches.
;;                                                                                                             ;;[I figured that I'd include this from hex cell aggregation for easy potential reference]
;; The "eligibles" list is used so that when we are trying to decide
;; what cell will become alive next, we don't have to check every
;; cell.  The list contains only those cells we know are eligible.
;; Every time a cell becomes alive, we remove it from the list.
;; We must also check that cell's neighbors to see if they need
;; to be added or removed from the list.

breed [cells cell]    ;; used to define cells                                                                  ;;[From hexagonal model examples]
breed [fires fire]    ;; bright red turtles -- the leading edge of the fire                                    ;;[From OG model]
breed [embers ember]  ;; turtles gradually fading from red to near black                                       ;;[From OG model]

cells-own [                                                                                                    ;;[All of cells-own is from hexagonal model examples]
  hex-neighbors       ;; agentset of 6 neighboring cells
  live-neighbor-count ;; used to store a count of red neighbors
  eligible?           ;; used to see if cells are eligible for ignition or not
]

to setup
  clear-all                                        ;; clears grid
  set-default-shape turtles "hex"                  ;; sets turtle shape to hexagonal                           ;;[Make sure to import the hex turtle shape from the library in Tools>"Turtle Shape Editor" first]
;;  ask turtles with [(random-float 100) < density] ;; random selection from density
;;    [ set color green ]                           ;; sets patch color to green
  ask patches with [(random-float 100) < density] [                                                           ;;[For the density parameter]
    sprout-cells 1 [                                                                                           ;;[For turtle creation]
      set color green                                                                                          ;;[Grid color like the OG model]
      set eligible? false
      if pxcor mod 2 = 0 [                         ;; if patch column is even,                                 ;;[For converting the square grid to hexagonal]
        set ycor ycor - 0.5                        ;; shift it down by 0.5
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ask cells [                                                                                                   ;;[Everything from here...]
    ifelse pxcor mod 2 = 0 [                 ;; setup for hex-neighbor agentsets
      set hex-neighbors cells-on patches at-points [[0  1] [ 1  0] [ 1 -1]
                                                    [0 -1] [-1 -1] [-1  0]]
    ][
      set hex-neighbors cells-on patches at-points [[0  1] [ 1  1] [ 1  0]
                                                    [0 -1] [-1  0] [-1  1]]
    ]
  ]                                                                                                             ;;[...to here for hex-neighbors]
  ;; set tree counts
  ask one-of turtles with [color = green] [                                                                   ;;[This can be moved to the go function and scrapped for a better approach if you want,
    set color red]                                                                                            ;; just wanted to demonstrate that a random single hex could be picked to start the fire]
  set initial-trees count turtles with [color = green];; counts the number of trees                           ;;[I felt like keeping counters for both of these but you can always remove/change them]
  set burned-trees 0                            ;; counts the number of burned trees
  reset-ticks
end

to go                                                                                                          ;;[Here's truly where all the problems lie haha]
  if not any? turtles                              ;; either fires or embers
    [ stop ]                                       ;; ends simulation
  ask fires                                        ;; otherwise, continue
    [ ask hex-neighbors with [color = green]                                                                  ;;[I tried a number of approaches here to no avail, there are probably tons of ways to do this]
      [ ignite ]                                   ;; burn them
      set breed embers ]                           ;; set them to fading burnt color
  fade-embers                                      ;; calls aesthetic function
  tick
end

to ignite                                            ;; patch procedure, creates fire                          ;;[This also is where things kinda ground to a halt for me lol]
  set eligible? false                                ;; changes cell state
  set eligibles remove self eligibles                ;; removes cell from list
  ask hex-neighbors [                                ;; checks neighbors
    set live-neighbor-count live-neighbor-count + 1  ;; adds to live neighbor count
    if live-neighbor-count = 6 [                     ;; if six neighbors active
      ask patches [                                  ;; [sprout-fires only
        sprout-fires 1                               ;;  works for patches]
          [ set color red ]                          ;; sets cell color to red
      ]
    ]
    update-eligibility                               ;; call for eligibility check
  ]
  set pcolor black                                   ;; sets patch color to black                               ;;[This needs to be affecting the turtle color but that creates problems I think lol]
  set burned-trees burned-trees + 1                  ;; adds to count of burned trees
end

to update-eligibility  ;; cell procedure
  ifelse eligible?
  ;; case 1: currently eligible
  [
    if not member? live-neighbor-count switches [ ;; checks if cell is in live count
      set eligible? false                         ;; since not, change cell state
      set eligibles remove self eligibles         ;; and remove cell from list
    ]
  ]
  ;; case 2: not currently eligible
  [
    ;; the check for hidden? ensures the cell isn't already alive
    if hidden? and member? live-neighbor-count switches [  ;; [potential need                                   ;;[This is right where the hex cells aggregation approach became too much for me lol,
      set eligible? true                                   ;; for use of hidden]                                ;; when everything got into hiding cells (I don't think the model should use hide/show)]
      ;; The order of the list doesn't matter, but in NetLogo
      ;; (as in Logo and Lisp generally), FPUT is much much                                                     ;;[This is directly from the hex cells aggregation example I think]
      ;; faster than LPUT.
      set eligibles fput self eligibles          ;; puts cell at start of list
    ]
  ]
end

to read-switches                                                                                                ;;[Admittedly I never got around to understanding how this works too well but somehow it's
  set switches []                                                                                               ;; more efficient, definitely might not be necessary though]
  if one-neighbor?    [ set switches lput 1 switches ]
  if two-neighbors?   [ set switches lput 2 switches ]
  if three-neighbors? [ set switches lput 3 switches ]
  if four-neighbors?  [ set switches lput 4 switches ]
  if five-neighbors?  [ set switches lput 5 switches ]
  if six-neighbors?   [ set switches lput 6 switches ]
  ask cells [
    set eligible? hidden? and member? live-neighbor-count switches
  ]
  set eligibles [self] of cells with [eligible?]
end

;; achieve fading color effect for the fire as it burns
to fade-embers                   ;; function for fading color of cells to show death                            ;;[This would be great to keep from the OG model but if it causes any issues you can delete it]
  ask embers
    [ set color color - 0.3  ;; make red darker
      if color < red - 3.5     ;; are we almost at black?
        [ set pcolor color                                                                                      ;;[I think this is where there's a problem of patches versus turtles]
          die ] ]
end
```

We tried to take out the eligibility of ignition since we really don't need it, still won't run :(
We tried to redo the code of 'to go' and 'ignite' still won't budge.

Comment: Also make sure that you import hex turtles from Tools > Turtle Shapes editor

Answer (score 0):

As you transitioned from a patch fire model to hex cells using turtles, in you ignite procedure, should you have cells hatching fires instead of patches sprouting fires?